# Mule File Inbound to read sub directories only once

Tags: mule

Is there a way to read only particular sub directories in mule using File inbound with recrusive="true" it is reading all the sub folders.

for example if there are directories as below, I would like to read changes in directories **folder2** & **folder4** only, but not all the folders. I do not want to have the file transport for each sub directory instead I would like to give its parent directory ***c:\test***

- C:\test\folder1
- C:\test\folder2
- C:\test\folder3
- C:\test\folder4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to read file(s) only once using File Connector. Instead I achieved this by using a [file watcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#register)  as a java component and storing the required attributes like file path and timestamp in queue. Later I'm polling for queue and reading the filePath and then processing the request